# Where in a WSDL contract is the wsdl version number defined?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I have grabbed a wsdl defintion from a live web service but cannot find which xml element or http link defines the version number of wsdl standard used.

Answer (score 2):

There is no version number in the WSDL. WSDL 2.0 uses a different namespace, `http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl"`, instead of `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/`.

Comment: @vanto: thought so, but couldn't find the reference on the w3c site fast enough.